# "Proclaimed [noun] X" or "Proclaimed [noun] as X"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I've seen both used, with "as" used more frequently, but it sounds wrong to my ears.

> The federal government has proclaimed January 8 National Ice Cream Day.

or

> The federal government has proclaimed January 8 as National Ice Cream Day.

Are both acceptable, is one more acceptable than the other, or is one incorrect?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This works like _elect, appoint, designate,_ etc. to specify a role or title to one argument. I've called these 3-place predicates, but they're not transfer predicates like _send, give, bring,_ or the like. They may just be a special construction with an extra NP after the object.

Comment: [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=proclaimed+him+king%2Cproclaimed+him+as+king&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) would indicate that while 'proclaim X as king' is not unknown, it is far rarer than the factitive usage. Ditto [named him president](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=named+him+president%2Cnamed+him+as+president&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) / as president.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Huddeston & Pullum (2002), *proclaim* can be used with or without the *as* (pp. 265, 279-280). To me, at least, both versions sound fine.

The only exception is when *proclaim* is followed by an infinitival verb phrase; in that case the *as* is forbidden, as shown by the fact that "He proclaimed them to be excellent" is correct but "He proclaimed them as to be excellent" is not.

Comment: To expand on the second paragraph, "proclaimed them [as] excellent" seems OK as well -- the infinitival phrase may not be necessary in the first place.

Comment: Now they are stylists, too?